# Poetry: Could not find a matching version of package abnumber

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am new to the Poetry dependency manager in python and am trying to transition my repo to use it.

So far, most things have gone well, but one package it can't seem to resolve is `abnumber`, which is found here:

https://anaconda.org/bioconda/abnumber

When I try to run:

```
poetry add abnumber
```

I get:

```
Could not find a matching version of package abnumber
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? I have tried manually specifying version numbers both in the command line and in the `pyproject.toml` file but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Poetry cannot handle conda repositories, because the repository structure and how the packages are build are very different from the python ecosystem.

By default Poetry will query [PyPi](https://pypi.org) for the package you are trying to add. And there it cannot find a one called `abnumber`.

Comment: Thank you for the information! How might I include that package in my environment? For everyone else who wants to use this repo, will they have to manually add that package to their poetry-constructed venv manually?